# Last value of hidden do not add to the total sum when checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to create an html file where the sum of the listed checkboxes are computed when a checkbox is ticked. One problem, I need the sum to be computed through the hidden input type value. This is because I need the value of my checkbox in the form. What I did is to loop through the checkboxes which are displayed in the form. My script is working, but the last checkbox to be ticked doesn't add it's value to the last sum of the checkboxes.

Here is my script:

```
function checkUnits() {
    document.AdvisingForm.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;
    var maxUnits = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.maxUnit))";
    for (i = 0; i < document.AdvisingForm.BSCS.length; i++) {
        if (document.AdvisingForm.BSCS[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.AdvisingForm.BSCS_units[i].value);

            if (sum > +maxUnits + 1) {
                alert("You have already exceeded the maximum number of units required for this semester. The maximum number of unit for this semester is " + maxUnits + ".");
                document.AdvisingForm.BSCS[i].checked = false;
                sum = sum - parseInt(document.AdvisingForm.BSCS_units[i].value);
            }
        }
    }

    document.AdvisingForm.total.value = sum;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add a fiddle ??

Comment: the values of checkboxes and the hidden input are generated dynamically through database.

Comment: When does your script call this function? Is it possible you're calling it before the last hidden input is being added to the DOM?